# Unable to send email notifications from jenkins

Tags: linux, email, jenkins, smtp

I am using Jenkins on linux.

I am not able to send email notifications through jenkins.
I have done the extended email setup as below[image]

And when I use the the configuration to send email using jenkins job as below
[image]
It throws the below error

```
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: my-email@live.com
ERROR: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout 60000
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:130)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:176)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:139)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:177)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:333)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:214)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: hey @DawidFieluba yes i tried and failed

Comment: Yes @DawidFieluba the msg is exact  same with the email id of gmail.

Comment: Your server name in configuration and error does not match: "localhost"?  Did you really save the global setting correctly? https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#system-wide-configuration

Answer (score 7):

**Enter your SMTP server information in the "E-mail Notification" section of the global configuration** instead of the "*Extended* Email Notification Plugin" section.

You're using the E-Mail notification "post-build" step. That is unrelated to the "Extended Email Notification Plugin", so it does not use the corresponding settings either.

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable "not secure app" connections in your Google Settings ?
It surely be mandatory to use the google account in third apps.